# I need my macro to prompt me to select a sheet based on the sheet names

Tags: xml, excel, worksheet, vba

I am running the following macro, but would like it to have more functionality. This spreadsheet is for maintaining customers and tracking sales values within multiple states. I have the workbook tabbed for each state I do work in. I want the macro to prompt me for which state I want to enter the data from the current macro. Can I add something to this macro so that it will first prompt me to select a sheet based on the sheet names?

```
Sub TestMacro()
Dim dblRow As Double, dtDate As Date, strCustomer As String
Dim strAddress As String, strZip As String, strEst As String
    dblRow = InputBox("What Row to Enter On")
    dtDate = InputBox("Date", , Date)
    strCustomer = InputBox("Customer")
    strAddress = InputBox("Address")
    strZip = InputBox("Zip Code")
    strEst = InputBox("Estimated Value")
    Range("A" & dblRow).Value = dtDate
    Range("B" & dblRow).Value = strCustomer
    Range("C" & dblRow).Value = strAddress
    Range("D" & dblRow).Value = strZip
    Range("E" & dblRow).Value = strEst
End Sub
```

Comment: I also forgot to add that I would like the dblRow = InputBox("What Row to Enter ON") to instead automatically select the next available row not containing data.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This is the working result of my code.

```
Sub EnterContact()
Dim lastrow As Long, strCust As String, strAddress As String
Dim strTown As String, strZip As String, strPhone As String
Dim strFax As String, strEmail As String, strContact As String
Dim strPrior As String, strOrg As String, strProj As String

With Sheets("Oregon")
    lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    strCust = InputBox("Enter Customer")
    strAddress = InputBox("Enter Address")
    strTown = InputBox("Enter Town")
    strZip = InputBox("Enter Zip Code")
    strPhone = InputBox("Enter Phone Number")
    strFax = InputBox("Enter Fax Number")
    strEmail = InputBox("Enter Email Address")
    strContact = InputBox("Enter Contact Name")
    strPrior = InputBox("Enter Priority Level")
    strOrg = InputBox("Enter Organization")
    strProj = InputBox("Enter Projected Dollar Amount")
    Range("A" & lastrow).Value = strCust
    Range("B" & lastrow).Value = strAddress
    Range("C" & lastrow).Value = strTown
    Range("D" & lastrow).Value = strZip
    Range("E" & lastrow).Value = strPhone
    Range("F" & lastrow).Value = strFax
    Range("G" & lastrow).Value = strEmail
    Range("H" & lastrow).Value = strContact
    Range("I" & lastrow).Value = strPrior
    Range("J" & lastrow).Value = strOrg
    Range("K" & lastrow).Value = strProj

Dim LRow As Long
'Find last row in Column A with content
   LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Row
   Rows("5:" & LRow).Sort Key1:=.Range("C3"), _
      Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
      OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
      Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

    End With
End Sub
```